# it should iterate till that number and follow condition and I don't want it should return None for 16th iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

** it should iterate until that number and follow the condition, and I don't want it to return None for the 16th iteration**
def fizzbizz(number):
for i in range(1,number + 1):
if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
print("fizzBuzz")

```
      elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 != 0:
          print("fizz")

      elif i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 == 0:
         print("Buzz")

      else:
         print(str(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
print(fizzbizz(15))

output is : 
1
2
fizz
4
Buzz
fizz
7
8
fizz
Buzz
11
fizz
13
14
fizzBuzz
None
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the function instead of just calling it, and the function returns None